# Calculate time difference from mutiple rows using SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, time

I have 2 tables, 01 is current status and 01 is finish status.
I want to calculate time difference of 2 rows that have the same PO_NO,MANAGEMENT_NO,PROCESS_NAME . 
Each PROCESS_NAME has the STATUS (Start/Finish)

```
ID  INDEXNO PO_NO   ITEM_CD MANAGEMENT_NO   SEQ PROCESS_NAME    STATUS  Time_Occurrence TimeDiff (Minute)
43  126690  GV12762 332393961   616244  6   RFID    Start   17-03-18 13:28  NULL
44  126690  GV12762 332393961   616244  6   RFID    Finish  17-03-18 13:29  0
49  141646  GV14859 7E7060100   619005  2   Imprint Start   19-03-18 13:23  NULL
50  141646  GV14859 7E7060100   619005  2   Imprint Finish  19-03-18 13:30  7
48  141646  GV14859 7E7060100   619005  1   R.M.Requisition Start   19-03-18 13:18  NULL
56  141646  GV14859 7E7060100   619005  1   R.M.Requisition Finish  19-03-18 15:54  156
```

The expected result is : TimeDiff (Minute) column

```
select PO_NO, [MANAGEMENT_NO],[STATUS] [Time_Occurrence],
datediff(minute, (isnull((select [Time_Occurrence] from [TBL_FINISH_STATUS] t1 where t1.id=t2.id-1), dateadd(dd, 0, datediff(dd, 0, getdate())))), [Time_Occurrence])TimeDiff
from [PROC_MN].[dbo].[TBL_FINISH_STATUS] t2  
ORDER BY PO_NO,MANAGEMENT_NO,ITEM_CD,Time_Occurrence
```

With above query, the result is far wrong with the expected result

Could anyone help me please?
Note: the ID column (48,56) of SEQ 1 of PO_NO: GV14859

Comment: Suggestion: Instead of a simple copy paste of data, if you provide it with consistent delimiters (like a comma), it would be much easier to create and test the data for everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you want, then this seems like a simple query for it:

```
select INDEXNO, PO_NO, ITEM_CD, MANAGEMENT_NO, SEQ,
       datediff(minute,
                min(case when status = 'Start' then Time_Occurrence end),
                max(case when status = 'Finish' then Time_Occurrence end)
               ) as timediff
from t
group by INDEXNO, PO_NO, ITEM_CD, MANAGEMENT_NO, SEQ;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/fd401/2) is a SQL Fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

It is not really clear what you are expecting as a result. Looking at your data sample, the design looks flawed from the start. There is too much redundancy for an SQL database. Maybe you don't have any control over the existing database. Anyway, this could be solved in N different ways and if my memory is not wrong, LEAD\LAG functions didn't exist in SQL server 2008 (but row_number is there as another solution). I tried to create something that is even compatible with older versions, but not sure if that is what you meant as a result:

```
DECLARE @myTable TABLE([ID] INT,
[INDEXNO] INT,
[PO_NO] VARCHAR(7),
[ITEM_CD] VARCHAR(10),
[MANAGEMENT_NO] INT,
[SEQ] INT,
[PROCESS_NAME] VARCHAR(15),
[STATUS] VARCHAR(6),
[Time_Occurrence] DATETIME,
[TimeDiff] VARCHAR(4));

INSERT INTO @myTable([ID], [INDEXNO], [PO_NO], [ITEM_CD], [MANAGEMENT_NO], [SEQ], [PROCESS_NAME], [STATUS], [Time_Occurrence], [TimeDiff])
VALUES(43, 126690, 'GV12762', '332393961', 616244, 6, 'RFID', 'Start', '20180317 13:28', NULL),
    (44, 126690, 'GV12762', '332393961', 616244, 6, 'RFID', 'Finish', '20180317 13:29', '0'),
    (49, 141646, 'GV14859', '7E7060100', 619005, 2, 'Imprint', 'Start', '20180319 13:23', NULL),
    (50, 141646, 'GV14859', '7E7060100', 619005, 2, 'Imprint', 'Finish', '20180319 13:30', '7'),
    (48, 141646, 'GV14859', '7E7060100', 619005, 1, 'R.M.Requisition', 'Start', '20180318 13:18', NULL),
    (56, 141646, 'GV14859', '7E7060100', 619005, 1, 'R.M.Requisition', 'Finish', '20180318 15:54', '156');

SELECT * FROM @myTable;

WITH
    Starters AS (
                    SELECT ID, PO_NO, [MANAGEMENT_NO], [PROCESS_NAME], [Time_Occurrence]
                    FROM @myTable
                    WHERE STATUS='Start'
                ),
    Finishers AS (
                     SELECT ID, PO_NO, [MANAGEMENT_NO], [PROCESS_NAME], [Time_Occurrence]
                     FROM @myTable
                     WHERE STATUS='Finish'
                 )
SELECT s.PO_NO, s.MANAGEMENT_NO, s.PROCESS_NAME, 
s.Time_Occurrence as [Start], f.Time_Occurrence as [End],    
DATEDIFF(MINUTE, s.Time_Occurrence, f.Time_Occurrence) AS TIMEdiff

FROM Starters s
     LEFT JOIN Finishers f ON s.PO_NO=f.PO_NO
                          AND s.MANAGEMENT_NO=f.MANAGEMENT_NO
                          AND f.PROCESS_NAME=s.PROCESS_NAME;
```